# RestKit and Coredata

Tags: objective-c, core-data, io, restkit

I recently documented about **Core Data** and after about **RestKit**.

I read that restKit can be used in conjunction with coredata..

I read a lot of material about but in the end I went to the confusion.

Can you tell me some good tutorials or examples for use with ***CoreData*** ***Restkit*** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tutorial I've found at the moment is "native" rest kit tutorial at there GitHub repository. https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md . There are quite a lot information. My advice is to do everything in that tutorial.